# move_base not executing, robot does not receive the goal

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, husky, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am doing SLAM using HUSKY A200, (ros1 kinetic on both end - robot and remote pc). I am using **hector mapping** for my mapping. I want to do SLAM without saving the map, just by using the 2D Nav goal in the rviz. I am using husky's **move_base**  for that purpose. I am using a **pepperl_fuchs_r2000 laser scanner.**

**My ROS master is set to in my remote pc .bashrc as:**

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://cpr-a200-0468:11311
```

Network config:
Husky:
ROS_IP: 192.168.131.1
ROS_HOSTNAME:cpr-a200-0468

Remote PC:
ROS_IP:192.168.131.10
HOSTNAME: rosi

**SETUP:**
**All my husky bringup scripts (navsat.launch, um7.launch, base.launch are added as robot_upstart script. Only r2000(laser), hector_mapping, move_base is launched from my remote pc.
I can rostopic echo /tf from my remote pc on husky boot up.**

I had some issues with the tf frames and time mismatch between the system.

```
TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame base_link
```

I solved those using other ros posts, also used  [chrony](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) for syncing the husky time with my remote pc time. Now I can get the scanned map but when I send the nav goal it does not execute.

I did publish my messages from rviz and tried listening over on husky end:

> rostopic echo /move_base_simple/goal

but no message appears on the husky terminal (sshed over wifi).
Just to make sure I send some cmd_velocity across the system from the terminal:

husky:

```
rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist "linea::
  x: 0.1
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0" 
publishing and latching message. Press ctrl-C to terminate
```

remote pc:

```
rostopic echo /cmd_vel
```

But I hear nothing but the robot moves.
Vice versa:

> remote pc: published
>
> husky listening: nothing received
>
> robot does not move.

The launch file launching the laser, hector_mapping and move_base is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <arg name="frame_id" default="base_laser"/>
  <arg name="scanner_ip" default="192.168.131.12"/>
  <arg name="scan_frequency" default="35"/>
  <arg name="samples_per_scan" default="3600"/>

  <!-- R2000 Driver -->
  <node pkg="pepperl_fuchs_r2000" type="r2000_node" name="r2000_node" respawn="true" output="screen">
    <param name="frame_id" value="$(arg frame_id)"/>
    <param name="scanner_ip" value="$(arg scanner_ip)"/>
    <param name="scan_frequency" value="$(arg scan_frequency)"/>
    <param name="samples_per_scan" value="$(arg samples_per_scan)"/>
  
 </node>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_odom_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom 100" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_baselink_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 odom base_link  100" />
 <!--- Run gmapping 
 <include file="$(find husky_navigation)/launch/gmapping.launch" />-->
<!-- <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="robot_state" args="0.35 0 0.15 0 0 0 base_link base_laser  10" /> -->
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find husky_description)/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro'" />
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />


<!--- Run Hector_mapping -->
<include file="$(find hector_mapping)/launch/mapping_default.launch" />
 <!--- Run Move Base -->
  <include file="$(find husky_navigation)/launch/move_base.launch" />


<!-- RVIZ -->
 
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="$(anon rviz)" respawn="false" output="screen" args="-d $(find pepperl_fuchs_r2000)/rviz/rviz.rviz"/>
</launch>
```

Images:
TF tree view before launching laser, hector_mapping, move_base : [C:\fakepath\before.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15362256786426905.png)

rqt_graph before launching laser, hector_mapping, move_base : [C:\fakepath\before_launch_laser.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1536225740559899.png)

TF tree view before launching laser, hector_mapping, move_base: [C:\fakepath\after.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15362257804520006.png)

rqt_graph before launching laser, hector_mapping, move_base : [C:\fakepath\after_laser.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15362258195711496.png)

I cannot figure out why the communication is not happening across the system. Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if I need to give any other information.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302546/move_base-not-executing,-robot-does-not-receive-the-goal/) by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2018-09-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-09-06**:
Have you correctly set the variable `$ROS_MASTER_URI` ?

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-09-06**:
Yes, I have the all the topics and laser scan and map coming streaming correctly. Additionally, both hosts are setup at the /etc/hosts communication is setup well i think.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-09-06**:
Is the issue only with the /cmd_vel topic ?
Can you also edit your question to add the launch file of the remote PC and the one of the robot ?

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-09-06**:
Added. Nope it is also the issue with the nav goals... When I send this over rviz: `Setting goal: Frame:base_link, Position(0.355, -0.558, 0.000), Orientation(0.000, 0.000, -0.679, 0.734) = Angle: -1.492`

I hear nothing on `rostopic echo /move_base_simple/goal` at the husky end.

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-09-06**:
However I can echo /tf and listen it in my remote pc  broadcasted from the husky.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-09-06**:
Can you provide the `rqt_graph` too please ?
It's normal that you can echo the tf because they are created from your remote PC, what nodes are you launching from the husky ?

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-09-06**:
I am assuming that you are echoing before you publish from your pc?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-06**:
Just making sure: can the Husky receive *any* messages from the PC?

If not: check `ROS_IP` and `ROS_HOSTNAME` settings and/or get a working DNS setup.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-09-06**:
Can you try this instead ?

```
rostopic pub -r 100 /husky_velocity_controller/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist "linear:
  x: 0.1
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0"
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-06**:
I would suggest to first make sure that bi-directional communication is working. Receiving msgs from the Husky is nice, but does not guarantee the other direction also work.

Just use `rostopic pub` with a `std_msgs/String` on the PC, try to `rostopic echo` on the Husky.

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-09-06**:
@gvdhoorn you are right, I just figured out the connection has fallen again. I cannot ping my remote pc from husky pc. However I can ping remote to husky. I thought I solved this issue by adding the hostname and ip  of the remote in husky pc (/etc/hosts) and vice versa

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-09-06**:
Also cannot hear any topic published in remote from husky.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-06**:
Please update your question with the values of `ROS_MASTER_URI`, `ROS_IP` and `ROS_HOSTNAME` for *both machines*.

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-09-06**:
@gvdhoorn I fixed the issue by setting the ip in my /etc/hosts in both the computer. Now I can hear on both ends. But I still cannot execute my 2D Nav goal, new errors are thrown. I will check the ros answers first for the errors. Or else I will create a new question. I guess that is recommended.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-06**:\

> ROS_IP: 192.168.131.1 ROS_HOSTNAME:cpr-a200-0468

If you set both `ROS_HOSTNAME` and `ROS_IP`, `ROS_HOSTNAME` will take precedence. If `cpr-a200-0468` cannot be resolved to an IP, things will stop working.

Either setup a DNS, use `avahi` or set only `ROS_IP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As suggested by @gvdhoorn I checked the ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME on my husky. I realized my husky could not listen from the remote pc but only husky to remote pc communication was working.

I have set IP of the remote PC in my husky. The alternatives are (quoted):

> If you set both `ROS_HOSTNAME` and
> `ROS_IP`, `ROS_HOSTNAME` will take
> precedence. Setup a DNS, or use `avahi`

---

Originally posted by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) with karma: 277 on 2018-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0